# PowerShell 7.0 and Windows PowerShell 5.1 Get-Member output with a Service object

Tags: powershell, .net-core

When I do the following in Powershell 7.0 on a Windows system:

```
    $obj = Get-Service -Name 'ajrouter'
   $obj | get-member
```

I get the following as the type :

System.Service.ServiceController#StartupType

I was expecting System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController as the type as I get that in Windows PowerShell 5.1, however I noticed when I looked for the System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController type I saw nothing for .NET Core. But then my question is what is PowerShell 7.0 doing to make this work ? What is the System.Service.ServiceController kind of type since I can't find it and what does #StartupType mean?

When I try

```
$obj = Get-Process -Name 'notepad'
$obj | get-member
```

I get the System.Diagnostics.Process which I noticed exists in .NET Framework and .NET Core. I hope I'm making the right statement here.

So how is PowerShell 7.0 getting an instance of a Service object ?

Thanks to anyone in advance

John

Comment: The `#part` after the actual type name are type hints that PowerShell use to distinguish formatting of different kinids of objects wrapped in the same .NET type - try piping any WMI/CIM instance to `Get-Member` :)

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean could you elaborate? Also why the differnce with a process object and a service object? And why does windows powershell 5.1 show System.Serviceprocess.ServiceController ? PowerShell 7.0 shows system.service.servicecontroller#startuptype

Comment: Now even funnier or not so funny maybe if I do the following in PowerShell 7.0 I first load the assembly system.serviceprocess and then create a new instance by typing $obj = new-object -typename System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController   and I then do a get-member on $obj I get the correct type system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller. So the only difference is getting an instance with a cmdlet.